# (iphone) uiscrollview not scrolling even though it receives touchesBegan/moved/ended event

Tags: iphone, touch, scrollview

I've set scrollView.userInteractionEnabled to NO so that superview catches the touch event.

In appropriate times, from one of my custom **view** class I call

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[scrollView touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
or moved/ended similarly.
```

I can see that my scrollView is getting the touche event messages with my debug output.
But I don't see it scrolling how could this be?

contentSize is big enough and scrollEnabled is YES.
(When I set scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES at start up, the scrollView scrolls fine)

for instance, my subclass of UIScrollView has

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{
    SYSLOG(LOG_DEBUG, "MyScrollView touchesBegan");
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
    [self setScrollEnabled: YES];
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

- Edit

overloading touchesBegan in a view class or view controller class makes a difference maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't just pass touches in and have it respond to them :(

You would have to use the [UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated:] method to move the scrollview yourself.

---

A better way of intercepting the touches might be to put a view in front of the scrollview - grab any touches you want to listen to and then pass it to the next responder in the chain.

You would make a subclass of UIView that overrode the touch handling methods, something like :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (scrollViewShouldGetThisTouch)
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

and just make this view have the same frame as your scrollview but be infront of it in the ui (transparent of course!).

OR

You could subclass UIScrollView - though this might result in odd errors if Apple ever change the implementation of a UIScrollView. I'd choose the other option!

Comment: oh.. i'll try this asap, Thanks. I thought touch gets handled in the deepest node (in view hierarchy) and up(so nextresponder from a subview would be parentview). I guess I got it wrong.

Comment: just to be sure, you mean, put a transparent view as a subview of the scrollview right?

Comment: i've put a empty view in front of scrollview (as sibling views), as feared, nextResponder is not scrollView but superview of the empty view

Comment: OK, in that case try `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]` and see if that helps? (I can never get the responder chain stuff to work first time!)

Comment: it didn't work, I think calling touchesBegan won't initiate scroll no matter what, but yes putting a view in front of scrollview can help intercept the touch